# Adding a Fresh Air Input for Furnace

Tags: hvac, furnace, vent

We recently purchased our first home and realized this input needs to be taking in air from outside versus the basement. Is this a project we can DIY or do we need to hire an HVAC specialist? We’re pretty handy and have a lot of tools. What would we need to complete this project correctly or does anyone have a link to a how-to guide? Also, does our filter need to be sealed in?

Thanks!

[image: Goodman furnance]

Comment: Can _you_ do it? No idea. Probably, but you'll have to be willing to learn some things and tear into your house. Ask us a specific question about a specific part of the task, not a broad, general, unanswerable question like this. Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we're a bit different than your general discussion forum.

Comment: If it wasn't installed properly, it wouldn't have passed inspection.   Some high efficiency furnaces require outdoor air.   Regular furnaces can use indoor air.  If it's a small space, a louvered door or wall vents may be required.  Get the model number and check the installation manual.

Comment: Title brought me here because I do this for a living and I wanted to see someone else having a hard time with it. Does that answer your question? ;)

Comment: Oh. Combustion air intake, not fresh air. That's... slightly more easy. But not if you don't own hole saws or masonry core bits. 'filters fine.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily *have* to draw combustion air from outdoors if combustion air is provided in another way, such as a combustion air intake grille admitting outdoor air into that room or airflow from the rest of the house. It is generally regarded as superior to connect this air inlet to the outdoors, though.

This does border on "licensed contractor" territory: some jurisdictions require that anything to do with installation, venting, gas, etc for fuel-burning appliances must be done by a licensed pro. Often there's an exception for a homeowner doing work on their own home.

Adding this intake plumbing is reasonably DIY-able for one who is comfortable with plumbing and framing. You'll need 2" PVC, fittings, solvent cement, etc. Goodman's installation manual has instructions as to the number of elbows, length of pipe, and size of pipe. At a certain threshold of burner capacity (BTU/h) and pipe length an up-size to 3" pipe is required.

The installation manual will (I think..) show examples of how the pipes may be terminated with turn-down elbows at a roof or wall exit. If the pipes exit through a wall, then a horizontal (or sidewall) vent termination kit is an attractive alternative. (Photo: diversitech.com)

[image: horizontal termination kit]

Comment: Thanks so much, Greg, this was super helpful!